# Get Azure VM status : "running , stopped" using resource manager deployment and rest api

Tags: rest, azure, virtual-machine

i've deployed a vm using Resource Manager deployment model.

Using rest api as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163682.aspx
i'm able to get informations about my VM. But i cannot see if the VM is running or not. I want that information to start/stop the VM Automatically via code.

Does anyone have tried that and get the VM powerstate?

best regards...

i make a GET using this URI

```
string.Format("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{2}?api-version={3}", subscriptionID, resssourcegroup, vmname,apiversion);
```

apiversion is 2016-03-30.

Comment: My bad , i needed to use the second uri to get information about the instance view of a virtual machine. How to make it resolved?

Comment: It would be good if you could put that as an answer to help anyone else who comes here with the same problem

Comment: A small hint: since the new .Net Framework, you are able to do such string formattings without String.Format. You can do it in a more intuitive way.
You just need it to like this:
string foo = $"This is my {number}. String in a row of {totalNumber} Strings";
There you can easily use your variables in the string and it's more readable.

Comment: @MichaelB-AzureMVP still looking how to make it as an answer.

Comment: @wuerzelchen thank you for  tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to use the second request uri "Get information about the instance view of a virtual machine" from the following url https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163682.aspx to get the instance powerstate.

Thank you.

Comment: I have the same problem, I don't understand what you mean by the second request uri.

Comment: the page documentation has changed. I guess you have to use this one : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines?redirectedfrom=MSDN#VirtualMachines_Get and analyze the response body for corresponding informations.But,
if you still want to know how to call 
 `var reqstring = string.Format("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{2}/InstanceView?api-version={3}",subscriptionID ,resssourcegroup, vmname, apiversion);` where `apiversion =2016-03-30`

Comment: I'm glad to help!

Comment: How did you know to put InstanceView in the URL?  I don't see that in the documentation.

Comment: It was in the previous documentation. Don't know where to find it now.

Comment: Working for version 2020-12-01 with the following url: /virtualMachines/{vmname}/InstanceView

Answer (score 1):

The API call for this information is:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{resource-group-name}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vm-name}/InstanceView?api-version={api-version}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the link to the documentation where you can see the Status of the VM:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtual-machines/instance-view?tabs=HTTP

This is an example of the output

```
"statuses": [
    {
        "code": "ProvisioningState/succeeded",
        "level": "Info",
        "displayStatus": "Provisioning succeeded",
        "time": "2022-07-25T02:12:52.7726725+00:00"
    },
    {
        "code": "PowerState/running",
        "level": "Info",
        "displayStatus": "VM running"
    }
]
```